# Getting only modified or new Kendo UI Grid rows to send to the server

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Although I have tried several times, I could not solve trying many method.
Shortly this is the thing what I want to do : only get modified or new rows as an object or JSON string.

Comment: Iterate on `dataSource.data()` and check for `dirty` flag.

Comment: OnaBai many thanks for your interest. When I edit a row, the dirty flag of the row does not change spontaneously. I change it in dataSource change event.

Comment: How do you change the value? It should get changed if you modify it using `set` (not if you modify it directly without `set`)

Comment: Although I use the set() method, it does not change the record's dirty flag.

Comment: And again, I have a trouble about update operation at the date column. I sent an email your address you shared at the your own blog.  Have you received it OnaBai?

Comment: No, I did not receive it!

Comment: It is the address you publish on the your contact page. I had sent through info@onabai.com

Comment: I am using below piece of code in my app and it work fine.  $.grep($("#gridname").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.view(), function (item) { return item.dirty == true; })

Comment: You can convert to json using json.stringify()

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use `set` for changing the content of a record. Then, getting the records modified is just iterating through `datasource.data()` array and checking which items have `dirty` set to true.

```
var data = grid.dataSource.data();
var dirty = $.grep(data, function(item) {
    return item.dirty
});
// Dirty array contains those elements modified
console.log("dirty", dirty);
```

The following snippet shows both that changing the data programmatically or via Grid built-in incell edition is compatible with this approach.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
      dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
          read:  {
            url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
            dataType: "jsonp"
          },
          update: {
            url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
            dataType: "jsonp"
          },
          destroy: {
            url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
            dataType: "jsonp"
          },
          create: {
            url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
            dataType: "jsonp"
          },
          parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
              return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
            }
          }
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
          model: {
            id: "ProductID",
            fields: {
              ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
              ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
              Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
            }
          }
        }
      });

  var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    navigatable: true,
    pageable: true,
    height: 300,
    columns: [
      "ProductName",
      { field: "Discontinued", width: 120 }
    ],
    editable: "incell",
    selectable: true
  }).data("kendoGrid");

  $("#change").on("click", function() {
    var sel = grid.select();
    if (sel.length) {
      var item = grid.dataItem(sel);
      item.set("Discontinued", true);
    }
  });

  $("#show").on("click", function() {
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    var dirty = $.grep(data, function(item) {
        return item.dirty
    });
    $("#logger").html(JSON.stringify(dirty, null, 2));
  });
});
```

```css
#logger {
  min-height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: scroll
}

#grid {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <div>
    This button changes the Discontinued field to "true" for the selected row: 
    <button id="change" class="k-button">Change selected</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    Click for displaying modified rows: 
    <button id="show" class="k-button">Show dirty</button>
    <pre id="logger"></pre>
  </div>
  <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very useful and comprehensive answer. Thanks a lot! I missed to set "batch" property as "true". Also The autosync property was left as "true". I think, ıt occurs  due to these. What about you? Also, I have sent an email again through your blog.

Comment: Got it this time. I'll reply you. Thanks